# Preventing Java Heap Space Error due to unknown cause in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I am currently working with a web development project by deploying its .war file directly through Wildfly inside Intellij.

The project loops through a list of urls where each contains a xml data file, retrieves each data file, and parses each data file.

Normally, each xml data file is about 5MB in size; however, every 1000 file would lead to a file that is around 50MB in size.

Whenever the program hits a 50MB file, I would receive a Java Heap Space error:

```
10:07:32,165 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (pool-13-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:367)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonGeneratorImpl.flushBuffer(JsonGeneratorImpl.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonWriterImpl.writeArray(JsonWriterImpl.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonWriterImpl.write(JsonWriterImpl.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonArrayBuilderImpl$JsonArrayImpl.toString(JsonArrayBuilderImpl.java:263)
```

In this case, I have increased my Intellij to 20GB in max heap size by changing its idea64.exe.vmoptions file, and the problem still persists.

Because of that, I don't think there is a shortage of heap space, and since I have implemented checks in the code to prevent not properly formatted file from being read, what other possibilities are out there that can cause the program to run into heap space error?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the vmoptions file is for IntelliJ - IntelliJ is written in java, so it has its virtual machine options. If I understood correctly you need to increase heap size on the server.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEB29XzDBm4) I found a tutorial on YT, might be helpful. If you come to a solution, answering your own question with all the required steps and marking it solved would certainly help others :)

Comment: For sanity's sake, make sure that you don't have any leaks in your program that might be causing the heap to run out of space.  Make sure you're cleaning up all instances of classes.  If an instance goes out of scope, make sure it's not left being referenced by any data structures that would prevent it from being garbage collected.